# Java Swing: Easy task, but I fail

Tags: java, swing, tree

I am not new to Java and OOP but I'm new to swing.

I want to write a software for building pedigrees. That means: right click into the middle of the drawing area and choose "New -> Man". A rectangle appears where I have right-clicked. Then I click on the rectangle and choose "New -> Sibling -> Woman" and the pedigree expands dynamically with a circle that is connected to the rectangle. You get the idea.

Additionally I need to save information for each node of the pedigree. Such as "mutation in gene x: positive".

I thought this must be perfect for OOP. I need every node of my pedigree to be an instance which draws itself into the drawing area. So ... a Jpanel? I extend JPanel, I give that class some attributes (such as "int mutationX = 1") and a method to add itself to the JFrame. At the moment I am only trying to add a rectangle into the middle of the screen via the menu. Easy step for a swing beginner. But the desired rectangle doesn't show up. So basically my questions are:

1. Am I even following the right approach of solving what I'm trying to achieve?
2. Why doesn't the rectangle show up?

---

```
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;

public class HelloWorld
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Hello World");

        JPanel mainpanel = new JPanel();

        JScrollPane scroll = new JScrollPane(mainpanel);

        frame.add(scroll);

        JMenuBar menubar = new JMenuBar();
        frame.setJMenuBar(menubar);

        JMenu file = new JMenu("File");
        menubar.add(file);

        JMenuItem exit = new JMenuItem("Exit");
        exit.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                        System.exit(0);
                    }
                }
        );

        file.add(exit);

        JMenuItem newMember = new JMenuItem("Add");
        newMember.addActionListener(
                new ActionListener(){
                    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae){
                        FamilyMember fm = new FamilyMember();
                        mainpanel.add(fm);
                        mainpanel.revalidate();
                    }
                }
        );
        file.add(newMember);

        frame.setLocation(400, 100);
        frame.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500,500));
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }
}

    public class FamilyMember extends JPanel {

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        super.paintComponent(g);
        g.drawRect(230,80,10,10);  
        g.setColor(Color.RED);  
        g.fillRect(230,80,10,10);
    }

    @Override
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(50, 50);
      }


}
```

Comment: You'll have to read more. mainpanel has (by default) a FlowLayout, so rectangles, when they appear, will appear right of each other, with the preferredSize you set to 50x50, while you paint after 230,80.

Comment: @LaurentG With a bit of expansion, that could be an answer..

Comment: @AndrewThompson I just answered the second part, the one that I can sum up tersly but enough to point the problems on the way. I just wanted to give hints to allow the OP to move on. I am not, by far, as efficient as you the (three?) big guys of swing on SO. I'll try to learn, but I can not promise anything.

Comment: @LaurentG *"I just answered the second part.."* Oh right, I didn't notice there were two parts. *"I just wanted to give hints to allow the OP to move on"* Nice work. :) OP: This is one of the reasons it's a bad idea to include more than one question per thread. Each question should be split into separate threads so that people who can only answer one of the two, can proceed to an answer.

Answer (score 0):

For the second point (why, a minima, it does not work/show any rectangle), you could take a look at Oracle docs (from more precise to broader concern) :

- [FlowLayout](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/flow.html)
- [Layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)
- [Swing panels](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)

In short,

your JPanel instance `mainpanel` has a FlowLayout as layout manager (which is the default for a new instance)

a flow layout will use each child preferred size

and you force the preferred size of your `FamilyMember` to 50x50

but you want to draw only south-east of 230,80 which is not in the 50x50 area.

=> it won't show.

For the first point, I'd say first : separate the model from the view.